# Hadoop 2.2.0 jobtracker is not starting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

It seems I have no `jobtracker` with Hadoop 2.2.0. JPS does not show it, there is no one listening on port 50030, and there are no logs about the `jobtracker` inside the `logs` folder. Is this because of YARN? How can I configure and start the job tracker?

Comment: Normally you do `start-yarn.sh`. What is your cluster properties and content of `slaves` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using YARN framework, there is no `jobtracker` in it. Its functionality is split and replaced by `ResourceManager` and `ApplicationMaste`r. Here is expected `jps` prinout while running YARN

```
$jps
18509 Jps
17107 NameNode
17170 DataNode
17252 ResourceManager
17309 NodeManager
17626 JobHistoryServer
```