# Hadoop 2.6 Cluster mapred-site.xml jobtracker port not listening

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have been trying so many configuration, yet it's impossible to have mapreduce jobtracker be listening if it's port (I'm on Hadoop 2.6),

As you can see the port 19999 is listening, which means that the configuraiton file mapred-site.xml is being read (since I specified this port for "mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address" to check)

```
netstat -plntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29375/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      865/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29866/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29509/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29509/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8030            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29866/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19999           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30053/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29866/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8032            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29866/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8033            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29866/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52897           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29995/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30053/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29509/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54310           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29375/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8040            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29995/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29995/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29671/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10033           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30053/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      865/sshd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60006           0.0.0.0:*                           533/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           533/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::14907                :::*                                533/dhclient
```

Please, can anyone help me troubleshoot this :

This is my configuration:

```
cat etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
<value>10.99.99.2:54444</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
 <description>The framework for running mapreduce jobs</description>
</property>



<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:19999</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>10.99.99.2:54333</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapreduce.job.tracker</name>
        <value>10.99.99.2:5431</value>
</property>



</configuration>
```

After every change, I do a full restart :

`/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/stop-all.sh ; /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh`

I have tried to put all property that I have found on Internet :

- mapreduce.jobtracker.address
- mapred.job.tracker
- mapreduce.job.tracker

Any help/comment is more that welcome

Here is the log of  mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.log :

```
2015-07-13 12:28:30,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting JobHistoryServer
STARTUP_MSG:   host = HM1/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop//contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/local/hadoop//contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/local/hadoop//contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/modules/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_45-internal
************************************************************/
2015-07-13 12:28:30,492 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-07-13 12:28:40,734 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-07-13 12:28:42,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: JobHistory Init
2015-07-13 12:28:48,084 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.jobhistory.JobHistoryUtils: Default file system [hdfs://0.0.0.0:54310]
2015-07-13 12:28:49,627 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.jobhistory.JobHistoryUtils: Default file system [hdfs://0.0.0.0:54310]
2015-07-13 12:28:59,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager: Initializing Existing Jobs...
2015-07-13 12:28:59,987 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CachedHistoryStorage: CachedHistoryStorage Init
2015-07-13 12:29:00,112 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2015-07-13 12:29:00,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 10033
2015-07-13 12:29:00,361 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-07-13 12:29:00,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-07-13 12:29:00,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobHistoryServer metrics system started
2015-07-13 12:29:00,697 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2015-07-13 12:29:00,706 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2015-07-13 12:29:00,715 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2015-07-13 12:29:00,982 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2015-07-13 12:29:00,999 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.jobhistory is not defined
2015-07-13 12:29:01,050 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2015-07-13 12:29:01,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context jobhistory
2015-07-13 12:29:01,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2015-07-13 12:29:01,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2015-07-13 12:29:01,066 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /jobhistory/*
2015-07-13 12:29:01,071 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /ws/*
2015-07-13 12:29:01,089 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 19999
2015-07-13 12:29:01,089 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2015-07-13 12:29:01,169 INFO org.mortbay.log: Extract jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar!/webapps/jobhistory to /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_19999_jobhistory____pblmcd/webapp
2015-07-13 12:29:02,607 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:19999
2015-07-13 12:29:02,607 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app /jobhistory started at 19999
2015-07-13 12:29:04,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Registered webapp guice modules
2015-07-13 12:29:04,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2015-07-13 12:29:04,201 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 10020
2015-07-13 12:29:04,222 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.HSClientProtocolPB to the server
2015-07-13 12:29:04,223 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2015-07-13 12:29:04,226 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 10020: starting
2015-07-13 12:29:04,235 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryClientService: Instantiated HistoryClientService at HM1/127.0.1.1:10020
2015-07-13 12:29:04,236 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2015-07-13 12:29:04,237 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 10033: starting
2015-07-13 12:29:30,708 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: History Cleaner started
2015-07-13 12:29:30,737 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: History Cleaner complete
2015-07-13 12:32:00,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-07-13 12:35:00,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-07-13 12:38:00,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
2015-07-13 12:41:00,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory: Starting scan to move intermediate done files
```

Here is jps

```
hduser@HM1:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ jps
24322 DataNode
25140 Jps
24485 SecondaryNameNode
24681 ResourceManager
24810 NodeManager
24188 NameNode
```

New configuration mapred-site.xml as suggested :

```
<configuration>
   <property>
<name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
<value>10.99.99.2:54444</value>
</property>


<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>local</value>
    <description>The framework for running mapreduce jobs</description>
</property>


<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:19999</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>10.99.99.2:54333</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapreduce.job.tracker</name>
        <value>10.99.99.2:54331</value>
</property>


</configuration>
```

I don't see any log related to jobtracker in logs folder. I have pasted the updated configuration

```
hduser@HM1:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ ls
hadoop-hduser-datanode-HM1.log    hadoop-hduser-namenode-HM1.out.3           mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.out    yarn-hduser-nodemanager-HM1.out.2
hadoop-hduser-datanode-HM1.out    hadoop-hduser-namenode-HM1.out.4           mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.out.1  yarn-hduser-nodemanager-HM1.out.3
hadoop-hduser-datanode-HM1.out.1  hadoop-hduser-namenode-HM1.out.5           mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.out.2  yarn-hduser-nodemanager-HM1.out.4
hadoop-hduser-datanode-HM1.out.2  hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-HM1.log    mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.out.3  yarn-hduser-nodemanager-HM1.out.5
hadoop-hduser-datanode-HM1.out.3  hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-HM1.out    mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.out.4  yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-HM1.log
hadoop-hduser-datanode-HM1.out.4  hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-HM1.out.1  mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.out.5  yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-HM1.out
hadoop-hduser-datanode-HM1.out.5  hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-HM1.out.2  SecurityAuth-hduser.audit              yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-HM1.out.1
hadoop-hduser-namenode-HM1.log    hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-HM1.out.3  userlogs                               yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-HM1.out.2
hadoop-hduser-namenode-HM1.out    hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-HM1.out.4  yarn-hduser-nodemanager-HM1.log        yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-HM1.out.3
hadoop-hduser-namenode-HM1.out.1  hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-HM1.out.5  yarn-hduser-nodemanager-HM1.out        yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-HM1.out.4
hadoop-hduser-namenode-HM1.out.2  mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.log        yarn-hduser-nodemanager-HM1.out.1      yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-HM1.out.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JobTracker and TaskTracker are no longer exists in Hadoop 2. JobTracker functionality split up into Resourcemanager and Applicationmaster.

Please refer [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852633/hadoop-2-2-0-jobtracker-is-not-starting)

You can find the similar question below.

[Hadoop 2.2.0 jobtracker is not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852633/hadoop-2-2-0-jobtracker-is-not-starting)

Comment: I have replaced "yarn" with "local", restarted all services, yet there is no jobtracker  listening :(

Comment: I need to have this port listening, since I want to use Elipse Hadoop plugin, in which I need to put this port in the section "Map/ReduceV2 (Master)"

Comment: Set **mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address** property to **10.99.99.2:54444** for http server address and port the server will listen on. Check [Mapred-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

Comment: I have Set mapreduce.framework.name to local
mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address to 10.99.99.2:54444
restarted everything. Still
Port 54444 is not listening when cheking with netstat :(

Comment: It seems the service is failed to start. Check the logs and pasted the same.

Comment: Ok, I have just pasted mapred-hduser-historyserver-HM1.log

Comment: Check with jps and check whether jobtracker running or not. If running you can find the port using its PID. We can't do anything with the history server log. Check for other service logs and find any exception occurs.

Comment: Ok, with jps jobtracker  is not running

Comment: So it should be problem with configuration. Logs can only help you to solve the issue.

Comment: I don't see any log related to jobtracker in logs folder. I have pasted the updated configuration

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks, so it's normal that there is no port listening for JobTracker. Thank you for your time