# Job Tracker and Task Tracker not running in Haddop?

Tags: xml, hadoop

In my hadoop installation i dont find mapred-site.xml file but it has mapred-site.xml.template.

I have added following property to mapred.xml.template

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Am i missing anything ?

**core-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

With these configurations:

```
http://localhost:50070/ : Running

http://localhost:50060/ : Not Running

http://localhost:50030/ : Not Running
```

Comment: Did you start the mapreduce too "start-mapred.sh".... whats the error you see there in log.

Comment: What version of hadoop?

[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978391/jobtracker-and-tasktracker-not-opening) might help.

Comment: Hadoop 2.4.0 and started using start-all.sh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Job Tracker and Task Tracker concepts are different in hadoop YARN. The links that you posted works only in old hadoop. In new version of hadoop you can monitor jobs being executed at

```
localhost:8088
```

where you will find the webUI for new hadoop. Also if you are using mapred-site.xml, you have to rename mapred-site.xml.template to mapred-site.xml. Add the properties that you want and restart the system.