# jobtracker and tasktracker not opening

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, replication, hdfs

i have successfully installed ubuntu 12.04 and hadoop 2.3.0.

after entering the jps command i find the output as below

```
4135 jps
2582 SeconadaryNameNode
3143 NodeManager
2394 Namenode
2391 Datanode
3021 ResourceManager
```

why it is not showing the jobtracker and tasktracker.
i tried start-mapred.sh but it shows command not found.(i searched the hadoop directory no such file found so i think the newer version i.e 2.0.3 has deprecated it and must be having some other way of starting jobtracker and tasktracker)

localhost:50070 working absolutely fine
but localhost:50030 and localhost:50060 shows unable to connect.

so anybody can help me out in this?

Answer (score 3):

You have installed the Hadoop 2.x with YARN. The Jobtracker and Tasktracker is replaced now with NodeManager,ResourceManager and Application Master. More Information about YARN (MRv2).

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html

Comment: okay that means nodemanager represets jobtracker & resourcemanager reprents tasktracker.??

Comment: wat about the localhost:50030 and localhost:50060 issues?

Comment: @user3677291 There are no direct equivalents of Job-Tracker and Task-tracker in YARN. The entire Architecture has been changed. Nodemanager and ResourceManager has different roles and responsibility then Job and Tasktracker. Since the Jobtracker doesnt exists the above urls wouldnt work anyway.

Comment: ok thanks but do you know how to perform an example on hadoop to know its working fine or not i have tried the hadoop-mapreduce-example.jar but m not sure m getting the right output or not

Answer (score 1):

To monitor the YARN based hadoop system you can use its WebUI which can be found at:

```
localhost:8088
```

Also If u want to view the stats regarding the jobs executed or view the logs generated you have to start the jobhistory server. It can be started by following command:

```
mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start history server
```

Once the history server is started you can view the logs generated at a single place. You can access history server at

```
localhost:19888
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your command to start the jobhistory server is slightly off.  No space between the word history and server.  My command was:  /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver.   /sbin vs. /bin is due to my version of Hadoop.